# No matching function for call to push_back

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, dictionary, binary-tree

I wanted to print a binary tree in the console and this was the code i wrote but I can't figure out this error. Could anyone please help me? The error is No matching function for call to push_back.

```
void getVerticalOrder(Node* root, int hd,std::map<int,std::vector<int> > &m)
    {
        // Base case
        if (node == NULL)
            return;
        // Store current node in map 'm'
        m[hd].push_back(root->payload); //Error in this line

        // Store nodes in left subtree
        getVerticalOrder(root->left, hd-1, m);

        // Store nodes in right subtree
        getVerticalOrder(root->right, hd+1, m);
    }
```

Comment: Is `payload` an `int`?  (As a general tip, you should post the entire error message on StackOverflow...)

Comment: no it is string @TonyD

Comment: You can not store string in `std::vector<int>`. You would need an `std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: Then why would you expect to be able to push a `string` into a `std::vector<int>`?  If you expect the `string` to hold a textual representation of an `int` then `.push_back(std::stoi(root->payload));` - see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).  If it might not be a valid `int`, and you don't want an exception thrown, follow Gypati's suggestion.

Comment: Oh yeah that was a very silly mistake.. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `payload` is string you need :

```
std::map<int,std::vector<std::string> >
//                         ~~~ vector of std::string
```